# MySQL query results in syntax error even though there is none

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to query my database using PDO and php. The file I'm querying from has multiple queries but the last one keeps failing for some reason. It tells me there was a syntax error, even though the syntax should be fine. The error is at different locations each time. Sometimes at the beginning of the query and sometimes at the end. Here is the query

```
    $feed_query = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM info WHERE id NOT IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $_SESSION["lgi_ids"])) . ') ORDER BY post_date DESC, votes DESC LIMIT 1');
```

I get an sqlstate 42000 error along with a 1064 syntax error or access violation error.

No matter what I try, I cannot figure out what's wrong. A simple query to the table works (without a where and order by) but this doesn't.

$_SESSION["lgi_ids"]is an array with numbers like 5,30,25,6 etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post a real query? ( `$query = 'SELECT id FROM info WHERE id NOT IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $_SESSION["lgi_ids"])) . ') ORDER BY post_date DESC, votes DESC LIMIT 1' ; echo $query ;` )

Comment: And the exact error message as well, since it provides a hint as to where the error could be.

Comment: @fusion3k I don't know what you mean by a real query

Comment: @Shadow I get different types of error messages. Some say the error is located near ('SELECT id, and some say that they're near LIMIT 1');

Comment: Do you think that the server might be running out of memory? And might have just stopped executing the query mid way?

Comment: If it is syntax error, it is not memory error. I gave you an example to obtain  “real query”. Your construct is fine, so we need to know the resulting query.

Comment: What @fusion3k means by "real query" is the query string *after* the `implode` and concatenation have done their work, that is, the text of the query the database is actually attempting to execute.